# How to edit and save data from gridcontrol to database using devexpress

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

This is my displayed data - I have this because I entered it into the database:

[image: Displayed data]

`ServiceRecord` and `EmployeeRecord` came from]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ56H.png):[result from postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQ56H.png)
This is my save method, my code is incorrect and I don't know what the right code is:

```
int rowendix;
rowendix = GV_ServiceRec.GetDataSourceRowIndex(GV_ServiceRec.FocusedRowHandle);

Type_ServiceRecord MyServiceRec = new Type_ServiceRecord
{
     EmployeeID = Txt_EmployeeID.Text,
     RecordID = Txt_RecordNumber.Text,
     JobTitle = GV_ServiceRec.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowendix,"JobTitle"),
     ServiceFrom = GV_ServiceRec.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowendix, "ServiceFrom"),
     ServiceTo = GV_ServiceRec.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowendix, "ServiceTo"),
     Salary = GV_ServiceRec.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowendix, "Salary"),
     EmploymentStatus = GV_ServiceRec.GetRowCellDisplayText(rowendix, "EmploymentStatus")
};
```

Comment: You don't. Devexpress controls are UI controls, not data access libraries. You load data into model classes and bind them to the UI, so the UI automatically updates the model when the user changes data. Then you use the same data access library you used to load the data (ADO.NET, EF, Dapper, NHibernate, whatever) to update the database.

Comment: BTW the tag you used is for a suite of web components while the screenshot looks like a desktop application. Devexpress has *extensive tutorials and samples too*, especially around data binding. That's one of the strongest selling points of any UI component suite. Have you checked the docs?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes. but i want to save the data  using a method..is that possible?

Comment: All code goes into methods. When you save your model you use a method. I suspect what you mean is pull the data from the grid instead of the model, the exact opposite of what both .NET and DevExpress tutorials do. Yes, obviously, but don't do that.  Read the docs *first* to understand how DevExpress, WinForms and ADO.NET work. Hard-coding access between the UI and data code is **very, very bad** and leads to overcomplicated, unmaintainable code. Instead of saving time by skipping the docs, you'll waste time as soon as you try to add another column

Comment: It's not OK thanks - you got the data into an object already. What prevents you from just saving it? Use your DbContext or a SqlCommand to save the data, just as you loaded it. This question doesn't really ask a question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i use this ``` GV_ServiceRec.SetRowCellValue(Cnt, "JobTitle", (string)MyRecord.ServiceRecord[Cnt].EmployeeRecord[0].JobTitle);```  so you mean i will use this code also to save the data to the database?

Comment: This doesn't load anything from the database. How did you load `MyRecord` ? Did you check the doc links? Apart from the designers and adapters they include code for [binding to DataTables](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2240/common-features/data-binding/how-to-bind-a-control-to-a-database-at-runtime) or [any other objects](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/2389/common-features/data-binding/how-to-bind-a-control-to-data-created-at-runtime). They don't explain how ADO.NET or EF or NHibernate works though - that's explained in ADO.NET, EF or NHibernate tutorials

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it just load the `JobTitle` row

Comment: No. It reads the text from an *already* loaded object. How did you load that object from the database? Did you use ADO.NET and SqlCommand? Or DataAdapter? Dapper ? Entity Framework? NHibernate? Whatever libraries you used to load that data are going to save the data too. Devexpress has nothing to do with this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ASP.NET and MSSqlServer